# Shut down after software closes

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to use Rpi3b solely for steamlink to my TV and found a tutorial that also shows how to set up steamlink to run on boot (sudo nano `.bash_aliases` and insert `steamlink`).

I'd like to automatically turn off raspbian when I close steamlink (so I can safely unplug without a keyboard/mouse). I found this answer:

```
sudo -s

someprogram && shutdown now
```

Does that mean I can edit the `.bash_aliases` to `steamlink && shutdown now`? Is it for simple commands only?

Answer (score 0):

It is worth a try to do as you suggested. Here are some hints in case it does not work as expected:

#### Use of .bash_aliases

Usually, `.bash_aliases` is not expected to be an autorun file. The "clean" way to do it would be to add a systemd unit, but I understand that might be too complicated for the problem at hand.

You say that you "close" streamlink -- for suggesting a better means of automatically starting it, it might be interesting how exactly the interaction with streamlink (e.g. closing it) works?

#### Use of &&

Shell script syntax `&&` means: Run the second command if the first one exited successfully. If you are using a common shortcut like CTRL-C to stop streamlink this might mean that it actually exits with a failure code. In that case, notation `;` would possibly be better (shutdown independent of return code):

```
someprogram; shutdown now
```

#### Shutdown usage permissions

There is another caveat to consider: On UNIX systems, shutdown is usually considered an action that can only be performed by the system administrator. On recent Linux systems, various mechanisms are in place to ensure shutdown also works as a regular user in case no other users are logged in etc. I recommend checking (before adding it to the autostart), if the `shutdown now` command works as expected. If it does not work, it might be necessary to setup sudo to allow the user to run shutdown.

#### An alternative solution

Finally, adding the shutdown directly after the program to run as described in this question generally works well. In case an application is more complicated (e.g. starts other processes and terminates before all of them have exited), it might be interesting to monitor the existence of the process by a separate script and trigger a shutdown once it is absent.